# Geotools add styleUrl

Tags: java, kml, geotools

Hi I am trying to build a DefaultFeatureCollection and add a styleUrl.

At the end i want to encode all this to a kml.

At the end of the method createStyle, i just print out the kml, to see how it looks.
My code looks like this:

```
public void createKML(List<VisualisierungsObjekt> visualList) throws ParseException, IOException,
            SAXException, TransformerException, KMLWriteException, URISyntaxException, SchemaException {

        final GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
        final WKTReader wkt = new WKTReader(gf);
        final List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();

        for (VisualisierungsObjekt objekt : visualList) {

            KmlStyling styling = STYLES.get(objekt.getColor_c() + objekt.getColor_f());

            if (styling == null) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                final String url = String.format("%s/rest/icon/%s/%s/25x25/circle.png", iconUrl, objekt.getColor_c(),
                        objekt.getColor_f());
                styling = new KmlStyling(objekt.getColor_c(), url, uuid);
                STYLES.put(objekt.getColor_c() + objekt.getColor_f(), styling);
            }

            String transformed = transformWKT("SRID=" + sridDB + ";" + objekt.getWkt());

            final Geometry point = wkt.read(transformed.split(";")[1]);

            SimpleFeatureType featureType = DataUtilities.createType("http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2", "KML_TYPE",
                    "styleUrl:String,description:String,Point:Point");

            final SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder type = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
            type.setName("KML_TYPE");
            type.setNamespaceURI("http://www.geotools.org/");

            final SimpleFeature feat = builder.buildFeature(String.valueOf(objekt.getId()));
            features.add(feat);

        }

        createStyle(features);

}

private void createStyle(List<SimpleFeature> features) throws TransformerException, IOException, SAXException {
        DefaultFeatureCollection collection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
        collection.addAll(features);

        KMLConfiguration configuration = new KMLConfiguration();

        Encoder encoder = new Encoder(configuration);
        List<String> namespaces = 
        Document document = encoder.encodeAsDOM(collection, KML.kml);
        document.normalize();

        Node docNode = document.getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(0);

        for (String key : STYLES.keySet()) {
            KmlStyling styling = STYLES.get(key);
            Element style = document.createElement("Style");
            style.setAttribute("id", styling.uuid());

            Element iconStyle = document.createElement("IconStyle");

            Element colorAttribut = document.createElement("color");
            colorAttribut.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styling.color()));

            Element scaleAttribut = document.createElement("scale");
            scaleAttribut.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1.0"));

            Element icon = document.createElement("Icon");

            Element hrefAttribut = document.createElement("href");
            hrefAttribut.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styling.url()));
            icon.appendChild(hrefAttribut);

            iconStyle.appendChild(colorAttribut);
            iconStyle.appendChild(scaleAttribut);
            iconStyle.appendChild(icon);

            style.appendChild(iconStyle);

            docNode.insertBefore(style, docNode.getFirstChild());

        }

        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transfomer = tf.newTransformer();
        transfomer.transform(domSource, result);

        System.out.println( writer.toString());

    }
```

At the moment the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<kml:kml xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <kml:Document id="featureCollection">
    <Style id="92dc97aa-c167-4939-a430-d18c44e0ba7b">
      <IconStyle>
        <color>00ff0000</color>
        <scale>1.0</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://link/to/icon/circle.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <kml:Placemark id="22">
      <kml:description>Hello new try</kml:description>
      <kml:ExtendedData>
        <kml:Data name="styleUrl">
          <kml:value>#92dc97aa-c167-4939-a430-d18c44e0ba7b</kml:value>
        </kml:Data>
        <kml:Data name="description">
          <kml:value>Hello new try</kml:value>
        </kml:Data>
      </kml:ExtendedData>
      <kml:Point>
        <kml:coordinates>11.512634059067835,48.532223718159365</kml:coordinates>
      </kml:Point>
    </kml:Placemark>
    <kml:Placemark id="23">
      <kml:description>Hello new11 try</kml:description>
      <kml:ExtendedData>
        <kml:Data name="styleUrl">
          <kml:value>#92dc97aa-c167-4939-a430-d18c44e0ba7b</kml:value>
        </kml:Data>
        <kml:Data name="description">
          <kml:value>Hello new11 try</kml:value>
        </kml:Data>
      </kml:ExtendedData>
      <kml:Point>
        <kml:coordinates>11.5127332365268,48.53231152627981</kml:coordinates>
      </kml:Point>
    </kml:Placemark>
  </kml:Document>
</kml:kml>
```

With the styleUrl in the ExtendedData, but want I want is something like this

`<kml:styleUrl>#92dc97aa-c167-4939-a430-d18c44e0ba7b</kml:styleUrl>`

Answer (score 0):

A quick grep of the KML module doesn't show any reference to `StyleUrl` so it looks like the code to handle it hasn't been written yet. We welcome pull requests that add functionality to the project.

Comment: Thanks for the info, in this case I add the styleUrl in an extra step. 
I will take a look at the geotools sourcecode and maybe if I have some spare time, I will create a pull request.